# How can I scroll inside of an element in selenium using java?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to scroll inside of an element using selenium but not able to succeed so far.
I tried some solutions I found on the web but without success.
I would like to select the last user from the following list.
Is anyone knows how can I do that? Notice that all the elements in the list have the same locator.

Thanks

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would do the trick:

```
Select select = new Select( driver.findElement(by) );
select.selectByIndex( select.getOptions().size() - 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code. If possible please share the test URL then I will replicate it from my side.

```
//get all the options from the dropdown list-
List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
//select last user from the list
action.doubleClick(allOptions.get(allOptions.size()-1)).perform();
```